# Aggregations on embeded documents not working

Tags: mongoid

I am trying to do some simple aggregations on embedded documents using Mongoid and it's not working although it works if the value is in the top level documents.

This works;

```
Accounts.avg("sale_price") 
>>  500.0
```

but if the field to average is in an embedded document it returns 0

```
Accounts.avg("sales.sale_price") 
>> 0.0
```

Am I using the wrong syntax to ref the embedded values or do these aggregation methods not work on embedded documents?

Comment: check the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367223/mongoid-aggregate-methods-on-embedded-docs) it may help

Comment: Yes I saw that question and answer.  The original question said that he got an error when attempting the aggregation on sub documents.  I am not getting an error, just an incorrect result so I thought maybe things had changed.  I know it's possible with mapreduce just thought maybe I was overlooking something obvious with the supported aggregation methods.